# JS get HTML `<template>` innerHTML with table content fails

Tags: javascript, html, templates

In an HTML file, I have the following content:

```html
<template id="notWorking">
    <table class="table table-xs table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Conteneur</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{ each(options.dossier.conteneurs) }}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ @this.numConteneur }}</td>
          </tr>
        {{ /each }}
      </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

But when I call `console.log(document.getElementById("notWorking").innerHTML)`, I get the following:

```
{{ each(options.dossier.conteneurs) }}

{{ /each }}
<table class="table table-xs table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Conteneur</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td>{{ @this.numConteneur }}</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

It seems that the element is not being parsed properly...? Am I doing something incorrectly?

See: https://codepen.io/nebrelbug/pen/OJJEvmW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<tbody>` can only have `<tr>` as children. Text content is not allowed.

Comment: For any who may have this same problem, I solved it by replacing `<template>` with `<script type="x-squirrelly-template">` (or whatever other type)